# Minus function not working in my activity

Tags: android, calculation

I want to reduce "previous meter reading" from current reading. But still bill calculation is done for current reading. Seems it's simple thing, But I can't find what the problem.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
    final double con = i.getDoubleExtra("Value", 0.0);

    final double pre = i.getDoubleExtra("Value1", 0.0);

    cur_units.setText("" + con);
    pre_units.setText("" + pre);

       Test = con - pre;

    Units = Test;
    if (Units <= 5) {
        Amount = Units * 12;
        Ser_Charge = 50;
    } else if (Units <= 10) {
        // For the First Five Units Charge = 60 (5 * 12)
        // Next, we are removing those 5 units from total units
        Amount = 60 + ((Units - 5) * 16);
        Ser_Charge = 65;
    } else if (Units <= 15) {
        // First Five Units charge = 60, and 6 - 10 is 80 (5 * 16)
        // Next, we are removing those 10 units from total units
        Amount = 60 + 80 + ((Units - 10) * 20);
        Ser_Charge = 70;
    } else if (Units <= 20) {
```

Comment: are you not getting the exact output? what is your problem? please explain.

Comment: I want to get units reducing previous meter units from current units.but bill calculating current unit only.

Comment: display your complete code. Tell me what is the data type of Units  and Test.

Comment: I can't add complete code. Bcoz too large.

Comment: double Amount, Ser_Charge, Total_Amount, Before_VAT, Units, Test;

Comment: Try putting Logs for Test, then Log inside each if statement and find out what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but you're not doing a great job of explaining the problem.

Comment: If Units is double why are you trying to subtract integers from it? make sure all the variables involved in your calculations are of the same type!

Answer (score 0):

Check your Units/Tests are double; if they  are int, con-pre result will be cast :
5.0 - 0.2 = 5

Comment: I suppose you checked that pre is  correctly set (not default value : 0.0) ?